# When I run msbuild, it makes a call to aspnet_compiler, but doesn't compile my site

Tags: msbuild, aspnet-compiler

I have created a custom .proj file that builds my web site project's solution.  It seems to all work correctly and it produces an output.  However, when I put it on the server, I got an error about "/Default.aspx is not precompiled and cannot be requested".  After some digging I discovered that indeed the precompiled aspx files were not precompiling.  In the output from msbuild, I found a call to aspnet_compiler:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /WebApplication -p WebApplication\ -f -fixednames Output_PublishedWebsites\WebApplication\
```

When I run this command directly, it generates everything just fine.

How can I get my msbuild wrapper to perform this correctly?

My msbuild task looks like this:

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFile)"
         Properties="OutDir=$(OutputRoot);
                     Configuration=$(AspNetConfiguration)"
         Targets="Build" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using the [<AspNetCompiler />](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164291.aspx) task.

Comment: any **full source code sample** or _usage sample_ ?